# highchart changes to UTC in jasperserver

Tags: highcharts, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I design a highchart using jaspersoft studio and then deploy it to the server. 
The time value in x axis is local time and it is fine in jaspersoft studio. But when I deploy it to jasperserver, the values comes up in UTC again.

If I just display the values in grids (not chart), the values are displayed in local time so all fine. But with the highchart, the problem emerges..

Can you help me with that

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem a while ago. I post my solution for the others who may face it.

JasperServer also makes a timezone conversation within itself whereas jasperSoft Studio does not as expected. That creates the contradiction..

Since Jasperserver makes the conversion automatically, I used the REPORT_TIMEZONE parameter to get the server's timezone and made the calculation of local time considering the conversion.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable UTC in highcharts by option:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
   global: {
       useUTC: false
   }
});
```

Docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.useUTC

Comment: Down voted because this doesn't answer doesn't explain how to set the property in Jasper Server studio.